# hosting large ML model on Flask or Node

Tags: node.js, flask

Hosting a machine learning model on Flask or Node should be relatively simple (e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-way-to-deploy-machine-learning-models-to-cloud-fd58b771fdcf).

However ML models are often super large, they might consume tens or hundreds of gigabytes of memory. In that context it probably wouldn't be a good idea to try to load them on every request. I'm just curious in the context of Flask, Node, etc, what people do to get around this fact. Is there a way to load the model only once and then use that loaded model to serve every request?

Comment: You have swappable memory in cases your ram is occupied. It's slower access but with SSD/NVME it's reasonably fast but in your regards you can increase Node's RAM limit. In your case however, you may do best running many threads per-core; that way a response may be fast some times but when system is busy it's a bit slower but utilized fully. You can implement a master node that communicates to slaves and utilize caching/etc; it all depends. Good luck.

Comment: The question is more, how do you make it so that you only have 1 instance of the model that can serve all requests. I think I might have found the answer for Flask in that you load it in the "main" code (`if __name__ == '__main__': my_model = [load model]`) and then you can refer to that in your other routes. You still will need a ton of RAM but you aren't instantiating the model once per call. Does that sound right?

Comment: FWIW I was referring to this tutorial, down under "your api.py should look like the following" https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/machine-learning-models-api-python